# Use Hall's Theorem to show that if $|N(S)| \ge |S| + 1$, $G$ has a perfect matching which contains an edge $e$.

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a bipartite graph $G$ with vertex classes $A,B$ where $|B|=|A|=n$.

Use Hall's Theorem to show that if $|N(S)| \ge |S| + 1$ for all $S \subseteq A$ with $S \ne A$ and $S\ne\emptyset$, then for an edge $e$ of $G$, $G$ has a perfect matching which contains $e$.

So far I can only link this to the fact that Hall's theorem implies that a bipartite graph with vertex classes $|A|$ and $B$ of equal size has a perfect matching iff $|N(S)| \ge |S|$ for all $S \subseteq A$.

Otherwise I don't have any idea how to go about this.

Comment: @user10354138 I have looked at that but I think my question is slightly different and the solution provided for that does not explain anything in much detail so I do not understand it.

Comment: @bof yes, my bad

Comment: You have no idea at all? Here's an idea. Suppose you delete the endpoints of the given edge $e$ from the graph; does the induced subgraph that remains satisfy Hall's condition?

Comment: @bof I have tried this for a few examples and see that it does, but am not sure how to prove that it does

Comment: After you delete the endpoints of $e$, the one in $A$ and the one in $B$, then any subset $S$ of what's left of $A$ will have almost as many neighbors as it did before, right? At worst, one less, if one if its neighbors was the endpoint of $e$ that's in $B$? If you had $|S|+1$ neighbors, and I took one of them away, how many do you have left?

Comment: @bof i think I understand! thank you for your help! will try to answer my own question on here